# How to add classmethod to a python class?

Tags: python, django, class

I'm trying to define a generate_username for my User class. (django's user)

The library code will make use of it..

```
def generate_username(self, user_class):
    """ Generate a new username for a user
    """
    m = getattr(user_class, 'generate_username', None)
    if m:
        return m()
```

How do I define and add the function `generate_username` to the User class?
I'm supposed to add a **classmethod** right?

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have?

Comment: the code above is the library code I don't wanna touch. and user_class (which is django's User class) is hard to subclass. getattr(user_class, 'generate_username', None) looks like  user_class.generate_username and I guess it's looking for a classmethod. So I ask how do I add classmethod dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a class method the same way you would monkeypatch an instancemethod but has you have to apply the `classmethod` decorator to it.

```
class Test(object):
    pass

@classmethod
def classfunc(cls, attr):
    print(cls, attr)

Test.cf = classfunc
```

Usage:

```
>>> Test.cf(33)
<class '__main__.Test'> 33
```

Comment: You can even use the `classmethod` as a decorator, to be more Pythonic: `@classmethod`